# (DELPHI 11 Alexandria) Exception in Notification processing

Tags: notifications, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm setting up an XmlRpc server. When analyzing a received command from the `OnCommandGet` event of a `TIdHTTPServer`:

```pascal
FServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
FServer.DefaultPort := StrToInt(Uri4port.port);
FServer.OnCommandGet := FServerCommandGet;
```

The command dispatch is OK, But the Notification process fails at the Presentation step:

```pascal
function CmdReceived_Decod.SampNotify(Lib: String): Boolean;
var
  S: String;
  now1: String;
  MyNotification: TNotification;
begin
  Now1 := DateTimeToStr(Now, AFormatSettings);
  if not Assigned(MyNotifCenter) then MyNotifCenter.Create(nil);
  Inc(Cpt_Notif);
  MyNotifCenter.CancelAll;
  //
  MyNotification := MyNotifCenter.CreateNotification;
  MyNotification.Name:= C_NomNotif + now1; // Nom Unique
  MyNotification.AlertBody := lib;
  MyNotification.Title := C_NotifTitle;
  MyNotification.Number := Cpt_Notif;
  MyNotification.FireDate := Now;
  MyMsgBox(lib, 'Samp_Vo', MB_OK);
     
  try
    Result := false;
    MyNotifCenter.PresentNotification(MyNotification);
  except
    on E: ELocalNotificationAccess do
      ShowMessage('Exception Type: ' + E.ClassName + ' =>  ' + E.Message);
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.Message);
  end;
  Result := true;
end;
```

The Exception message is:

```
" Sortie de débogage:
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx(6563)\combase.dll!7688696F: (caller: 751C64A4) ReturnHr(1) tid(eb0) 8001010E L’application a appelé une interface qui était maintenue en ordre pour un thread différent."
```

In English : `"application called an interface kept in state for a different thread"`

I closely verified that the notify sequence works in a standalone environnement, and that the full process worked without notifications.

Are notifications prohibited in the `OnCommandGet` event?

How to work around this?

---

UPDATE:

According to the given answer, the call is successfully modified as:

```pascal
TH1 := MainThreadID; 
TH2 := GetCurrentThreadId;
NeedSync := not(TH1=TH2);
If NeedSync then
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin 
    SampNotify(Lib); end)
else SampNotify(Lib);
```

Comment: You don't need to (and should not) edit your question to indicate which answer works for you. Simply upvote and accept the answer that helped you the best.

Comment: BTW, `MyNotifCenter.Create(nil)` is wrong, it should be `TNotificationCenter.Create(nil)` instead. Don't ever call a class constructor via an object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check from which thread SampNotify() is called. Probably this is not the main thread. You can get the current thread ID using with GetCurrentThreadId, and the main thread ID with MainThreadID. If the code is indeed running on a separate thread, synchronizing the call to SampNotify() might solve this problem:

You can do something like this:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin SampNotify(); end);
```

Comment: Note that `TThread.Synchronize()` checks the `MainThreadID` internally, so you can call `Synchronize()` unconditionally from any thread and it will "do the right thing" for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like most of Indy's servers, `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component. It fires its `OnCommand...` events in the context of worker threads, not in the context of the main UI thread.

The error message is telling you that you are accessing the `TNotificationCenter` object from a thread context that is different than the one it was created in.  Internally, `TNotificationCenter` uses COM objects, and most COM objects in the Win32 API are apartment-threaded, so they can't be used across thread boundaries without marshaling them, such as with `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()`+`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()`  or `IGlobalInterfaceTable`.

So, you should either:

1. Create a separate `TNotificationCenter` instance per worker thread. You will also need to call `CoInitialize/Ex()` and `CoUninitialize()` per thread (which you can do in the server's `OnConnect` and `OnDisconnect` events).
2. Create the `TNotificationCenter` in the main UI thread only, and then use `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Notify()`, or Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify`, when you need to execute code in the context of the main UI thread.